# CSS offset a tooltip

Tags: html, css

I am trying to attach a tooltip to a button.

```css
    .hangup_button {
      display: block;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      margin-bottom: 25px;
    }

    .contained_message {
      visibility: hidden;
      width: 120px;
      background-color: black;
      color: #fff;
      text-align: center;
      border-radius: 6px;
      padding: 5px 0;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 1;
    }
    .messageContain:hover .contained_message{
      visibility: visible;
    }
```

```html
  <div class="container_div">
    <button class="hangup_button messageContain">
      End Chat
      <span class="contained_message">Terminate session. Charges stop accumulating.</span>
    </button>
  </div>
```

The problem I have is that the tooltip appears at the bottom of the button. I am trying to make it appear to the top of the button. So far, I tried to switch the `<span class="contained_message">` to the top of the `End Chat` text. But the tooltip still exceeds the bottom of the button. I also tried to add `position: relative;` to `.contained_message`. That seems to mess up the whole button. What should I do in order for the tooltip to appear on top of the button, without exceeding the bottom of the button?

Comment: Something with `position: absolute` will position itself within it's nearest positioned parent. If you want it positioned absolutely inside of the button, add your `position: relative` to either `.messageContain.` or `.hangup_button`

Comment: This will help for future references - https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added some changes to make it work:

1. Use `position: relative` on parent element.
2. Use `transform: translate` to get the desired placement, as well as `top: -5px` (can be 0, but -5 gives it a nice space)
3. I changed it to `display: none / block` instead of using visibility, as it may be more desirable (providad you are not looking to do transitions).
4. To center the tooltip horizontally, `left: 50%` with `translate(-50%, ...)` does the trick.

**Working snippet:**

```css
    .hangup_button {
      display: block;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      margin-bottom: 25px;
      margin-top: 80px;
      position: relative;
    }

    .contained_message {
      display: none;
      width: 120px;
      background-color: black;
      color: #fff;
      text-align: center;
      border-radius: 6px;
      padding: 5px 0;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 1;
      transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
      left: 50%;
      top: -5px;
    }
    .messageContain:hover .contained_message{
      display: block;
    }
```

```html
  <div class="container_div">
    <button class="hangup_button messageContain">
      End Chat
      <span class="contained_message">Terminate session. Charges stop accumulating.</span>
    </button>
  </div>
```